# C# [Design] lost .. only .designer left

Tags: c#, visual-studio, delete-file, windows-forms-designer

I did a huge plunder and accidentally lost my `*.cs` (Design file).. I just got the `*.designer` file left.

Can I go the other way around and create somehow a Design-File (`*.cs`) only with the `.designer` file or do I have to start over?

Comment: Please have a look in recycle bin

Comment: Alas no. The designer file contains the code to create and position all the UI elements. The best you can do is to use the other file to glean the names of the UI elements. And start using Source Control - there are many good free options, such as [Git](http://git-scm.com/).

Comment: alright thanks.. apperantly there was the right file in the bin but its  corrupted i cant add it to my project.. and thanks for the advice.. now i am smarter :/

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look in Recycle Bin and click restore. So you will get your file back in visual studio solution explorer with excluded status. Right click and include in project.

To avoid this type situations, use version controls in your project like:

- [TFS - Team Foundation Server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/tfs-overview-vs.aspx)
- [GIT](http://git-scm.com/)
- [Visual Source Safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181038%28en-us,vs.80%29.aspx)
- [SVN](https://subversion.apache.org/)

Comment: if i may add another one, SVN

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't send files to the recycle bin when deleting from the solution explorer.

Comment: @slugster Are you sure about this. Test it yourself and let me know. Any file deleted from VSS will go to recycle bin. In windows all deleted files from file system will go to Recycle Bin unless your pressing Shift + Delete

Comment: Yes I am absolutely 100% positive about it - it even says so in the confirmation dialog ("permanent deletion"). TFS doesn't send them to the recycle bin either. You mentioned VSS which is SourceSafe - I can't remember if that does or not.

Comment: @slugster OP didn't mention about using any source control. So I suggested to go for one of listed source controls. So in future, accidentally deleted file can be recovered by using source control.